# Mi programa de python se queda atascado en una linea

Tags: python

estoy tratando de modificar la lista "magos" para que en vez de los nombres diga "The Great nombre", pero se traba el programa en la linea 13.

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
print("Los nombres de los magos son:")
for magician in magicians:
    print(magician.title())

magos = ['fabrizio','julian','florencia']

show_magicians(magos)

def make_great(magicians):
    while magicians:
        mago = magicians.pop()
        magicians.append(f"The Great {mago}")
    
make_great(magos)

show_magicians(magos)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar en qué consiste la función _make_great_? (que te sirva de [patito de goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_depuraci%C3%B3n_del_patito_de_goma)).

Comment: La funcion make_great toma la lista de magos y la va leyendo , primero voy sacando los elementos de la lista (nombres de los magos) y los guardo en una variable, despues agrego a la lista esa variable pero con "The Great" primero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la iteración, `while magicians:` siempre validará como `true` por lo cual, es un ciclo infinito que nunca se detendrá y te deja la sensación de que tu programa queda en espera.

La solución es cambiarlo por un `for - in` o agregar banderas al `while` para que la iteración tenga una salida definida.

Ejemplo:

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
i = 0
while i < len(thislist):
  print(thislist[i])
  i = i + 1
```

Aún así, dentro del ciclo no hará lo que tu esperas, por lo cual te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    print("Los nombres de los magos son:")
    for magician in magicians:
        print(magician.title())

magos = ['fabrizio','julian','florencia']
show_magicians(magos)

def make_great(magicians):
    for position in range(len(magicians)):
        magicians[position] = "The Great {}".format(magicians[position])
        
make_great(magos)
show_magicians(magos)
```

En el caso anterior podemos notar que nuestro ciclo ahora está echo por el largo de la lista, y en base a eso accedemos a los diferentes magos por su posición para luego reemplazar el valor anterior (con la posición del elemento de la lista).

Si no quieres reemplazar el valor simplemente puedes agregar los magos a una nueva lista y retornarla en la función.

Comment: muy claro, muchas gracias